# Application of type-level arguments of Kind other than Type

Tags: haskell, type-kinds

I would like to be able to explicitly apply an argument of kind other than `Type` to a dummy constructor purely for documentation purposes. However `TypeApplications` does not seem to support this scenario:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, PolyKinds, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications #-}

data EQ :: k -> k -> * where
  Refl :: EQ a a

data Wrap (a :: k) = Wrap (EQ a a)

wrap :: forall (a :: k). Wrap a
wrap = Wrap @a Refl
```

leads to the error

```
ProxyApply.hs:9:14: error:
    • Expected a type, but ‘a’ has kind ‘k’
    • In the type ‘a’
      In the expression: Wrap @a Refl
      In an equation for ‘wrap’: wrap = Wrap @a Refl
    • Relevant bindings include
        wrap :: Wrap a (bound at ProxyApply.hs:9:1)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I wonder if it’s a type checker bug to do with the way kind variables are passed around implicitly. What happens if you say `Wrap @k @a Refl`?

Comment: Oh, wow. That works. `Wrap @_ @a Refl` also works in case the `Kind` you want to use is long and you don't feel like writing it down. Do you mind posting this as an answer?

Comment: Lucky guess! :) I'll post an answer, but I think it should probably also be reported as a GHC bug.

Comment: I'll report it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you’ve found a type checker bug.

The way kind variables are implemented, GHC passes around an extra type parameter behind the scenes. This type parameter is supposed to be implicit and filled in by unification, but sometimes it shows up. (That's why you sometimes see extra type parameters in Haddocks, eg in [`Proxy`'s instance list](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Proxy.html).)

This appears to be one of those situations: the type checker thinks you’re passing the `k` parameter. Luckily it seems like you can work around it by passing the kind variable explicitly.

```
wrap :: forall (a :: k). Wrap a
wrap = Wrap @k @a Refl
```

Comment: Apparently this is [the expected behaviour](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/14348#comment:1). To not have this you have to leave the kind annotation `(a :: k)` out when defining `Wrap`.

Comment: @gallais Interesting! Thanks for the link. I for one have a general mistrust of `TypeApplications` and surprising behaviours like that aren't doing much to convince me otherwise 

Comment: It's indeed a shame that you *have to* leave documentation out of your code to get the behaviour you want. I guess a solution would be to make a distinction between user-written and user-introduced (e.g. `Wrap (k :: Kind) (a :: k)` vs. `Wrap (a :: k)`.

Comment: Well, running `:t Wrap` in GHCi does print `Wrap :: forall k (a :: k). EQ a a -> Wrap a`, so it should be reasonably clear that both `k` and `a` must be passed. It would make sense to pass only the type arguments, and not the kind ones, but if we ask to be explicit, we need to be explicit about everything. It feels a bit like Coq or Agda when we need to pass everything to satisfy a dependently-typed function.

Comment: @gallais Why do you say that "you have to leave documentation out"? I don't understand.

Comment: @chi: [My use case](https://github.com/gallais/potpourri/commit/9b04cb49aeb91db61272878c5ae1cad0904c24b4#diff-45d21eaa70370a2acf5767454a2f4e74L47). Consider `cong :: forall (f : Function k l -> *) a b. a == b -> Apply f a == Apply f b` versus `cong :: forall f a b. a == b -> Apply f a == Apply f b`.

Comment: @gallais I'd write that as `cong :: forall k l (f : Function k l -> *) a b. ...` and pay the `@_` price. (That works, right?) If that is too much for your use case, then I think I understand now.